# Converting hair to mesh in python script

Tags: mesh, particles

I'm working on my own renderer for learning purposes. I'm currently using Blender as a UI host for my renderer. My renderer can export mesh by using my plugin in Blender. However, it doesn't convert the hair into mesh automatically. I have to convert it manually every time after I have hair particle modification.

Could anyone share me some pointer on how to convert it to mesh in a python script?

Thanks